# Mysql получить список адресов электронной почты из строки

Tags: mysql

Как на mysql получить адреса электронной почты, если они хранятся по несколько штук в каждой записи. 
То-есть например:

```
user | email
------------
1 | 1@fff.ru, asdasd@ddd.com , фывй@ffdf.ru 
2 | 124@fasdff.ru, asadsd@asddd.com , qqqq@df.dd
..................
```

Мне нужно получить список этих адресов. 
Как можно заметить там разделитель `,`, но бывает что перед ней после нее или  и там и там есть пробел...

Comment: Получить куда? Почему бы не сделать простой `select email from таблица` и разделить по запятым в используемом вами языке программирования?

Comment: А зачем вообще хранить через запятую и добавлять себе гемора? Не проще ли просто сделать идентификатор для пользователя и по нему искать его емаилы, раз на то пошло. Ибо если будет очень много пользователей, искать всех сразу, а потом искать емаилы, будет накладно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var somemails= '1@fff.ru, asdasd@ddd.com , фывй@ffdf.ru'; 
var cleanEmails=somemails.split(',');
console.log(cleanEmails);
```

```
SELECT email FROM somtable;
```

[php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)
[js](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)